# Should questions be marked as "duplicate" if answered before, but a possibly better/simpler approach now used?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

How to prevent possibly better/simpler approaches to a previously answered question from getting buried as a duplicate question ?

[Number of ways to arrange identical coins in a ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716491/number-of-ways-to-arrange-identical-coins-in-a-ring/1716697#1716697)

Comment: That's not a bug report. Rather it seems you want discuss the subject.

Comment: Ok, what I meant was that  a duplicate gets marked as a duplicate regardless of the new answer(s) possibly having additional utility.

Comment: You may post an answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio) to persuade others to reopen that question and mark the others as dulpicate instead.

Comment: Yes, but first this is not a bug, in the sense of an error or malfunction in the software, or an erratic or unspecified behavior.  Second, the answer is still visible, and in this case there is no auto forward, contrary to the situation without answer. So this is even explcitly accounted for and it is not clear in which sense it is even buried. Other than that you can always answer the other question. In case the questions are indentical you could ask a mod for a merge.

Comment: @JohnMa: Thanks, I don't think I shall bother for this question, but now I know what to do, if it is needed !

Comment: @quid: Thanks, I understand.